# How to reduce the Xpath to make it shorter?

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I am trying to get the value of a menu item in an Angular wesbite. If I put the detailed Xpath, I can select the menu item from the drop down.

How would I get the XPath significantly shorter?
Apologies if this is a terrbile question, I am pulling my hair out!

I have used the exact XPath but my code got rejected when I checked in.

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("/html/body/modal-container/div/div/inv-education-modal/article/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/inv-drop-down-select/section/div/ul/li[3]/a/span"));
```

I actually want to pass a parameter so it selects the relevant dropdown value, but it's an Angular site so I can't use a SelectElement.

Comment: The problem with that xpath is it's very dependent on the exact structure of the entire page. That makes it very fragile - if any part of the structure changes, your selenium test will break. Does the menu or menu item, or one of its near parents, have an `id` or `class` you can use?

Comment: We would have to see the markup of the site in question to tell you how you could shrink your XPath.

Comment: There is no shorter XPath expression that is precisely equivalent to the one you have supplied. There are other expressions that might give the same result when applied to some particular document of known structure, but the equivalence will only apply to some source documents and not to others.

Comment: Share the HTML. Without that, we can't construct a relative XPath.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an [`<a>` tag](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_a.asp) before your [`<span>` tag](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_span.asp) which indicates a [hyperlink](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperlink).

Normally hyperlinks have [`href` attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_href.asp) and the associated text like:

```
<a href="http://example.com>Click me!</a>
```

which will look in your site as:

[Click me!](http://example.com)

a "shorter" XPath which will look for a hyperlink with "Click me" text will look as:

```
//a[@href='Click me!']
```

and if you want the next `span` - `//a[@href='Click me!']/span`

References:

- [XPath Tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp)
- [XPath Operators & Functions](https://docs.experitest.com/pages/releaseview.action?pageId=40044727)
- [XPath Playground](https://scrapinghub.github.io/xpath-playground/)